# Laravel PostgreSQL Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "table.column" must appear in the GROUP BY

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql

I've 2 tables that I want to **select** without **duplicate rows** here my eloquent syntax :

```
 $historyEx  = new HistoryExchange();
        $historyEx  = $historyEx->with([
            'history.transaction_detail',
        ]);


        $historyEx = $historyEx->offset($start)
                         ->limit($limit)
                         ->orderBy($order,'asc')
                         ->groupBy('history_id')
                         ->get();
```

here my eloquent syntax is working fine on **MySQL** cause I was **disabled strict mode**

But when I moved to PostgreSQL, it's show me error

> Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column "history_exchanges.id" must appear in
>   the GROUP BY

here is the
[error screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ol1.png)

and here structure of the tables :

- Table History Exchanges : [structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4wos.png)
- Table History : [structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtR22.png)
- Table Transaction Details : [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpRb4.png)

and it should display one row with

[Output Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87mF5.png)

Does any one know how to disable group by strict on PostgreSQL or have any solutions to fix it?

Comment: PostgreSQL wants correct group by queries.

Comment: so what's the solution ?